# How to print Paskal's Triangle in Java

Tags: java, pascals-triangle, triangle

Can I print this with triangle shape in Java?

I tried to print this with only border "1"s:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[5][5];


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    matrix[i][i] = 1;
    matrix[i][0] = 1;

}
```

Comment: You're missing code, please share all you have, the current output and the expected output [edit] your post for that

Comment: "*Can I print this with triangle shape in Java?*" - Yes. --- On a sidenote: It's called Pas**c**al's triangle, named after [Blaise Pascal (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal).